# System reboot seemingly no reason, no logs, only IMPI mentions after reboot

Tags: linux, ipmi, reboot

One server reboots every few days seemingly completely randomly. There is no mention in any log of any errors prior to such a reboot. For example, the reboot happens in between these 2 messages from `/var/log/messages` and `journalctl`:

```
Mar 13 11:25:01 server something: some action 
Mar 13 14:33:00 server rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="2460" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

The only clue I could find is after the reboot, somewhere in the start up it spouts out this IPMI line:

```
Mar 13 14:33:00 server kernel: [   24.621566] Copyright (C) 2004 MontaVista Software - IPMI Powerdown via sys_reboot.
```

All the other IPMI and other messages seem to be normal. The motherboard of this server is an Intel S5000PSL. Some outputs from `ipmitool`:

```
# ipmitool mc watchdog get
Watchdog Timer Use:     BIOS FRB2 (0x01)
Watchdog Timer Is:      Stopped
Watchdog Timer Actions: Hard Reset (0x01)
Pre-timeout interval:   0 seconds
Timer Expiration Flags: 0x00
Initial Countdown:      0 sec
Present Countdown:      0 sec
```

Does the IPMI keep other logs that I don't know of and if so, how do I access them?

Comment: Try to enable maximum power in BIOS settings and disable processor c-states and other energy saving. It's just simple recommendation to find decision of this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem, next step was logging over serial console to another machine without any result. Fianl solution was support request to vendor. I got new motherboar, from then everything is OK